# Problem with opening new window in Safari in Full Screen mode

Tags: macos, safari

When Safari window is in Full Screen mode there's a combination option+command+N to open a new window (not a tab!). But on my MacBookPro2020 it doesn't work sometimes. I can't figure out when it would work and when not and why there is such a problem. Is it just a bug or I'm going something wrong?

P.S.: I have this problem for several months. I reloaded my MacBook during this period lots of times and I still bump into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the shortcut doesn't work, do this:

File menu > New window.

Then onwards, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> will start working.

Comment: But why does it happen and should it work like that? I guess it's a bug and maybe sb knows how to deal with it

Comment: @MarkTiukov no it shouldn't work like this. It's a bug and this is the workaround to use till its fixed. https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/welcome

Comment: Thx! The menu doesn't display command+N, but it maps to "new tab", in full screen mode. I thought "(real) new window" simply didn't work, until now.